# Boolean calculation: Do 'and' and 'And' share the same meaning in colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, google-earth-engine

I have two codes about image mask in Google colab:

(1)

```
mask1 = img1.gt(0.5) and img2.lt(1.2)
```

(2)

```
mask2 = img1.gt(0.5).And(img2.lt(1.2))
```

Are they different?

Does mask1 equal mask2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two different things. `And()` is a server-side operation and `and` is a client-side operation. You have to use the server-side operation for this. You can read up on client- vs server-side [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server).